# Full Screen hides HTML controls in Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I tried to implement a full screen functionality in my application . Its working fine .But I added some HTML controls in my aspx file ,when i click onr fullscreen  button it shows a fullscreen but not show a HTML controls( only shows a SilverlightHost UI) .

So how can I resolve it. (I have set windowless property true).

Thanks in advance,
Laxmilal

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, then this behavior is normal, and that's by design; putting a Silverlight application in full screen means precisely that it will occupy all the available screen space, hiding anything else. Maybe what you need is a *full-screen browser window* instead (you can achieve this using Javascript, see for example here: http://www.pptools.com/ppt2html/FAQ00140.htm)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the silverlight plugin with the Windowless property set to true the silverlight application will draw on the same window as the other html contols.  Hence its possible to place HTML controls on top of content presented by silverlight.

However when you put silverlight in full screen mode it is **silverlight** you are full screening not the browsers client window.  Therefore sivlerlight needs to create a new window which it then full screens, the silverlight app then renders on to this new window.  As result any HTML content is occluded.

Comment: I have tried to update the html page text box again after Full Screen property, but it shows behind Silverlight Control. Windowsless property is true till now.

Comment: I am trying this code line for Full Screen Silverlight control.

Application.Current.Host.Content.IsFullScreen = ! Application.Current.Host.Content.IsFullScreen;

Comment: Mucking about with the `IsFullScreen` property isn't going to help.  It simply isn;t possible to properly full screen a silverlight application and continue to see the HTML controls.  The best you can do is manipulate the browser window (if that is possible) to make that as large as it can be.  However there is no standard way to make a browser full screen.